# How to complete the following JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, target

Being new to JavaScript, I can't seem to understand how to get the JavaScript to correctly remove the existing text in the text box and move it underneath the box after the user begins typing.

I have been following this video http://codepen.io/ehermanson/pen/KwKWEv/ (where you can see what I mean when you type in the field) but instead I am using the compiled CSS to complete the task however the uploader has not included a CSS alternative for the JavaScript and uses SCSS so I do not know how to complete the task.

Here is my code below. Dreamweaver also indicates that in my JavaScript code there is a "use strict" statement missing and that 'target' is not defined. I believe my HTML and CSS are good but please feel free to indicate if otherwise.

```js
  
$('.form').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function(e) {

 var $this = $(this),
    label = $this.prev('label');

  if (e.type === 'keyup') {
    if ($this.val() === '') {
      label.removeClass('active highlight');
    } else {
      label.addClass('active highlight');
    }
  } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
    if ($this.val() === '') {
      label.removeClass('active highlight');
    } else {
      label.removeClass('highlight');
    }
  } else if (e.type === 'focus') {

    if ($this.val() === '') {
      label.removeClass('highlight');
    } else if ($this.val() !== '') {
      label.addClass('highlight');
    }
  }

});

$('.tab a').on('click', function(e) {

 e.preventDefault(); 

  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

 target = $(this).attr('href');

  $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();

  $(target).fadeIn(600);

});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #454545;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #179b77;
}

.form {
  background: #5C5C5C;
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 5px rgba #1D1D1D;
}

.tab-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}
.tab-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.tab-group li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(160, 179, 176, 0.25);
  color: #454545;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.tab-group .active a {
  background: #FF8216;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-content > div:last-child {
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
          transform: translateY(6px);
  left: 13px;
  color: #F9F9F9;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 22px;
}
label .req {
  margin: 2px;
  color: #FF8216;
}

label.active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
          transform: translateY(50px);
  left: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
label.active .req {
  opacity: 0;
}

label.highlight {
  color: #454545;
}

input, textarea {
  font-size: 22px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #a0b3b0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
  transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #FF8216;
}

textarea {
  border: 2px solid #454545;
  resize: vertical;
}

.field-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.top-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.top-row > div {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 4%;
}
.top-row > div:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.button {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  background: #FF8216;
  color: #454545;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
  background: #FFAD51;
}

.button-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.forgot {
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" script src="login.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


<div class="form">
      
      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Your Personal Orlangutan</a></li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="signup">   
          <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>
          
          <form action="/" method="post">
          
          <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                First Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password" required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          
          <button type="submit" class="button button-block">Get Started</button>
          
          </form>

        </div>
        
        <div id="login">   
          <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
          
          <form action="/" method="post">
          
            <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password" required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          
          <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
          
          <button class="button button-block">Log In</button>
          
          </form>

        </div>
        
      </div><!-- tab-content -->
      
</div> <!-- /form -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you don't use placeholder ? When you call the function that register the events ?

Comment: I can't see that you have explained what the code is meant to do or what problem you are having. I appreciate that we _could_ watch the video, but people do not have time for that - can you edit the post to be a bit clearer?

Answer (score 1):

You must add the reference for **jquery** as CDN or local

```
// CDN
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

// Local the file must exist on the same folder of the html page
<script src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

Recall the code after DOM ready.

You can place the code after the last DIV and BEFORE the `</body>`

**or**

place the entire script on a separate file,wrap it inside a function

```
  function startup() {
     // code here
  }
```

Include it with

```
<script type="text/javascript" script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

And then call the function directly after the last div like this

```
<script>
    startup();
</script>
```

or on dom ready

```
<script>
   $(function(){
     startup();
   }
</script>
```

I have made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ea6btgh8/)

Comment: I'm sorry Max Its not working for me. I'm not too sure what a 'DOM ready' is?

I have copied the code from "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" as you said and entered this into a new JavaScript file on dreamweaver and linked it on my HTML page at the bottom of my page after the last DIV and Before the closing </body> tag.

I'm trying to follow the LOCAL method. Could you please help me with the next following steps to do with JavaScript? 

I have copied the code you have entered in your JSFiddle. Thankyou so much for you help.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Google Chrome. I don't know if this helps

Comment: copy the jquery-2.2.3.min.js into the same folder of the html page, then add the `<script src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>` inside the `<head>` tag of the page, then place your code BEFORE the `</body>` tag

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-object-assign@1.1.0/dist/object-assign-auto.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/text-encoding@0.6.4/lib/encoding.min.js"></script>  I wanted these cdn locally so i downloaded these and added <script src="./js/encoding.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/object-assign-auto.js"></script>.... But uít doesnt work

Comment: Please help me reolve it

Comment: Follow the instructions for local deploy: [es6-object-assign](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-object-assign) and [text-encoding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-encoding). PS text-encoding has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery before your login.js

This is from CDN 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

You can also download jquery and add locally also.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this. How would I add jquery before my login.js? Thankyou for your help!